# multiple sed with -e and escape characters

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to do multiple replacements in a gzipped file and have been having trouble.

```
zcat PteBra.fa.align.gz | sed -e 's#Simple_repeat/Satellite/Y-chromosome#Simple_repeat/Satellite#g' -e sed 's#Unknown/Unknown/Y-chromosome#Unknown/Unknown#g' -e sed 's#DNA/DNA/TcMar#DNA/TcMar#g' -e sed 's#DNA/DNA/Crypton#DNA/Crypton#g' -e sed 's#DNA/DNA/PIF-Harbinger#DNA/PIF-Harbinger#g' -e sed 's#DNA/DNA/CMC-Chapaev-3#DNA/CMC-Chapaev-3#g' -e sed 's#SINE/SINE/RTE#SINE/RTE#g' > PteBra.fa.align.corrected
```

Note that I'm using # instead of the standard / because of the presence of / in the text I want to replace. Each individual sed works with no problem but stringing them together yields this consistent error:

```
sed: -e expression #2, char 3: unterminated `s' command
```

I have looked all over for a solution but finally, to get the work done, just did all the sed's individually. It takes FOREVER, so I'd like to get this option working.

I've been at this for hours and would appreciate some help.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `sed` must only appear once, no need to repeat it after each `-e`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to write `-e sed` each time! `-e` will do.

```
zcat PteBra.fa.align.gz | sed -e 's#Simple_repeat/Satellite/Y-chromosome#Simple_repeat/Satellite#g' -e 's#Unknown/Unknown/Y-chromosome#Unknown/Unknown#g' -e 's#DNA/DNA/TcMar#DNA/TcMar#g' -e 's#DNA/DNA/Crypton#DNA/Crypton#g' -e 's#DNA/DNA/PIF-Harbinger#DNA/PIF-Harbinger#g' -e 's#DNA/DNA/CMC-Chapaev-3#DNA/CMC-Chapaev-3#g' -e 's#SINE/SINE/RTE#SINE/RTE#g' > PteBra.fa.align.corrected
```

or you can use semicolon inside sed string expression itself

```
zcat PteBra.fa.align.gz | sed -e '
s#Simple_repeat/Satellite/Y-chromosome#Simple_repeat/Satellite#g;
s#Unknown/Unknown/Y-chromosome#Unknown/Unknown#g;
s#DNA/DNA/TcMar#DNA/TcMar#g;
s#DNA/DNA/Crypton#DNA/Crypton#g;
s#DNA/DNA/PIF-Harbinger#DNA/PIF-Harbinger#g; 
s#DNA/DNA/CMC-Chapaev-3#DNA/CMC-Chapaev-3#g;
s#SINE/SINE/RTE#SINE/RTE#g
' > PteBra.fa.align.corrected
```

Comment: Or simply make it a single expression separated by `';'`, e.g. `sed 's#Simple_repeat/Satellite/Y-chromosome#Simple_repeat/Satellite#g;s#Unknown/Unknown/Y-chromosome#Unknown/Unknown#g; ...'`

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a proper answer, this is not yet another answer
but a small suggestion for the actual operation.
I imagine writing the `sed` command in a line may be a messy job. How about
preparing a look-up table which describes a replacee and a replacer
in a line as a csv format like:

**table.txt**

```
Simple_repeat/Satellite/Y-chromosome,Simple_repeat/Satellite
Unknown/Unknown/Y-chromosome,Unknown/Unknown
DNA/DNA/TcMar,DNA/TcMar
DNA/DNA/Crypton,DNA/Crypton
DNA/DNA/PIF-Harbinger,DNA/PIF-Harbinger
DNA/DNA/CMC-Chapaev-3,DNA/CMC-Chapaev-3
SINE/SINE/RTE,SINE/RTE
```

Then you can execute the following `awk` script to replace the strings:

```
zcat PteBra.fa.align.gz | awk -F, '
    NR==FNR {repl[$1] = $2; next}
    {
        for (r in repl) gsub(r, repl[r])
        print
    }
' table.txt - > PteBra.fa.align.corrected
```

Hope this helps.